# Could not find com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.5.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I want to use this GitHub library but when I try to rebuild the app or try to run on my device it shows me **Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.**
[image]

I have added the repository in my root gradle as follows :
[image]

And have also add the dependencies in my app gradle file :
[image]

Is there any possible solution? I really want to use this library in my project..

Comment: I see you have set the plugin to version 7.0.0 from the build.gradle file using 'classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'. This [table](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) lists which version of Gradle is required for each version of the Android Gradle plugin. For plugin version of 7.0 we need 7.0+  required Gradle version.

Comment: You can specify the Gradle version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or by editing the Gradle distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file using :
'distributionUrl = "https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.0-all.zip"'. Android Gradle plugin 7.0.0 is a major release in July 2021. When using Android Gradle plugin 7.0 to build your app, JDK 11 is now required to run Gradle. For more information visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this error by putting `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`
this line of code into settings.gradle (repositories) and removing the same from build.gradle(project level) and it worked for me!